# Can not used LAPS-Cmdlets from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to execute the LAPS cmdlets from C#. The LAPS module exists on the target computer. I can execute the LAPS cmdlets in the console and ise.

- I tried to execute basic cmdlets and everything worked fine
- I tried to execute for example cmdlets from the ActiveDirectory module and everything worked find

This is what i have done so far ...

```
var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new[] {"LAPS"} );
//initial.ImportPSModulesFromPath(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\LAPS\LAPS.psd1");

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.Open();

try
{
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                powershell.AddScript(@"Get-Command -Module LAPS");

                foreach (PSObject obj in powershell.Invoke())
                {
                    switch (obj.ImmediateBaseObject)
                        {
                            case ErrorRecord errorRecord:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"[ERR] {errorRecord}");
                                    break;
                                case VerboseRecord verboseRecord:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"[VER] {verboseRecord}");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"[OUT] {obj}");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    runspace.Close();
}
```

I get no error message. Where is my mistake? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you expect an error? And why do you assume the result is `PSObject`, I get `CmdLetInfo` and `FunctionInfo`

Comment: You never look for errors. Inspect `powershell.HadErrors` and `powershell.Streams.Error` after calling `Invoke()`

Comment: @Charlieface That part is correct, `PowerShell.Invoke()` returns a collection of `PSObject`'s, the base objects of which will be `CommandInfo` objects returned by `Get-Command`

Comment: I run into the same problem - try to call Get-LAPSADPassword - it is working from Powershell itself - but if I try to call it from c# the cmdlet can't be found. Any help why this is not working in c#???

Comment: I've found a little difference - don't understand in detail - but perhaps we can figure it out - LAPS CmdLet's can only be run if you start WindowsTerminal session - you can see it by starting just a process from .NET application - if you start Powershell.exe and try to run any LAPS-CmdLet it is not working - if you start wt.exe (Windows Terminal) you can use the LAPS CmdLets - but in that case it is not possible to redirect the standard output correctly - seems to be not working correctly - but I guess it is the way we need to go ahead!